# rxJava buffer() with time that honours backpressure

Tags: java, rx-java2, project-reactor

The versions of `buffer` operator that don't operate on time honour backpressure as per JavaDoc:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#buffer-int-

However, any version of `buffer` that involves time based buffers doesn't support backpressure, like this one

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#buffer-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-int-

I understand this comes from the fact that once the time is ticking, you can't stop it similarly to, for example `interval` operator, that doesn't support backpressure either for the same reason.

What I want is a buffering operator that is both size and time based and fully supports backpressure by propagating the backpressure signals to BOTH the upstream AND the time ticking producer, something like this:

```
someFlowable()
.buffer(
     Flowable.interval(1, SECONDS).onBackpressureDrop(),
     10
);
```

So now I could drop the tick on backpressure signals.

Is this something currently achievable in rxJava2? How about Project-Reactor?

Comment: This is not available in RxJava or Reactor at the moment. There is an [implementation](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow/blob/master/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/reactive4javaflow/impl/operators/FolyamBufferBoundary.java) in a prototype library though if you are willing to backport it.

Comment: OK, I see. I can certainly give it a shot. Is this operator scheduled to be included in rxJava2?

Comment: No, maybe in RxJava 3. Up until then, we don't want to break the behavior of existing time- or timing-driven operators. Reactor is more affectable, so maybe they are willing to accept it for 3.2.

Comment: Right so! I see and thanks for your time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the problem recently and here is my implementation. It can be used like this:

```java
    Flowable<List<T>> bufferedFlow = (some flowable of T)
                              .compose(new BufferTransformer(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 8))
```

It supports backpressure by the count you've specified.

Here is the implementation: https://gist.github.com/driventokill/c49f86fb0cc182994ef423a70e793a2d

Comment: where is `BufferTransformer` taken from? Where's the implementation?

Comment: Here is the implementation: https://gist.github.com/driventokill/c49f86fb0cc182994ef423a70e793a2d

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136139/6719538 when used `DisposableSubscriber` as subscribers, and as far as I can see this transformer don't consider calls `Suscription#request` from downstream subscribers (it could overflow them). I create my version that was tested in production - [BufferTransformerHonorableToBackpressure.java](https://gist.github.com/fedor-malyshkin/e1b460959d91d37664dc329af3c5fc17). [fang-yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/883330/fang-yang)  - great respect for idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had a look at this again and somehow it struck me that this:

```
public static <T> FlowableTransformer<T, List<T>> buffer(
    int n, long period, TimeUnit unit)
{
    return o ->
        o.groupBy(__ -> 1)
         .concatMapMaybe(
             gf ->
                 gf.take(n)
                   .take(period, SECONDS)
                   .toList()
                   .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
         );
}
```

is pretty much doing what I described.
That, if I am correct is fully backpressured and will either buffer n items or after specified time if enough items haven't been collected

Comment: Something is not right with this implementation. It works fine for some time and then nothing gets emitted out of it. Nothing obvious comes to my mind. Perhaps chaining two `take()` like this is not working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I had another go at it that lead to a quite overengineered solution that seems to be working (TM)

**The requirements**:

1. A buffering operator that releases a buffer after a time interval elapses, or the buffer reaches maximum size, whichever happens first
2. The operator has to be fully backpressured, that is, if requests cease from downstream, the buffer operator should not emit data nor should it raise any exception (like the starndard Flowable.buffer(interval, TimeUnit) operator does. The operator should not consume its source/upstream in an unbounded mode either
3. Do this with composing existing/implemented operators.

**Why would anyone want it?**:

The need for such operator came when I wanted to implement a buffering on an infinite/long running stream. I wanted to buffer for efficiency, but the standard Flowable.buffer(n) is not suitable here since an "infinite" stream can emit k < n elements and then not emit items for a long time. Those k elements are trapped in buffer(n). So adding timeout would do the job, but in rxJava2 the buffer operator with timeout doesn't honor backpressure and buffering/dropping or any other built in strategy is not good enough.

**The solution outline**:

The solution is based on `generateAsync` and `partialCollect` operators, both implemented in https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions project. The rest is starndard RxJava2.

1. First wrap all the values from upstream in a container class `C`
2. Then `merge` that stream with a stream which source is using `generateAsync`. That stream uses `switchMap` to emit instancesof `C` that are effectively timeout signals.
3. The two merged streams are flowing into `partialCollect` that holds a reference to an "API" object to emit items into the `generateAsync` upstream. This is a sort of feedback loop that goes from `paritialCollect` via the "API" object to `generateAsync` that feeds back to `partialCollect`. In this way `partialCollect` can upon receiving the first element in a buffer emit a signal that will effectively start a timeout. If the buffer doesn't fill before the timeout, it will cause an instance of empty `C` (not containing any value) flowing back into `partialCollect`. It will detect it as a timeout signal and release the aggregated buffer downstream. If the buffer is released because of reaching its maximum size, it will be released and the next item will kick off another timeout. Any timeout signal (an instance of empty `C`) arriving late, aka after the buffer has been released because of reaching maximum size will be ignored. It is possible, because it's the `partialCollect` that instantiate and sends out the timeout signal item that will potentially flow back to it. Checking the identity of that item allows to detect a late vs legitimate timeout signal.

**The code**:
https://gist.github.com/artur-jablonski/5eb2bb470868d9eeeb3c9ee247110d4a