# RxJava Operator that dynamically buffers backpressured elements and emits them in batches

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I have a Flowable that emits events that need to be handled by an expensive operation which expects element arrays:

```
Flowable<T> src
void expensiveOp(List<T> batch)
```

Other than using a constant window i'd like to specify a window of *max* elements that is filled while downstream is busy and when full just backpressures:

```
int maxSize = 1024
src.dynamicWindow(maxSize).subscribe(expensiveOp)
```

The size of the window should therefore be neither constant-time nor element but backpressure dependent. The buffer should be flushed when the subscriber is ready to process the next element.

What overloaded method am I missing?

Possible extensions would be a minSize parameter and a retry mechanism that retries with an increased window.

Comment: Sounds like you need [`coalesce`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformerscoalesce)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the problem recently and here's my original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136139/883330

For a quick answer. My implementation to support backpressure with time and count based buffer: https://gist.github.com/driventokill/c49f86fb0cc182994ef423a70e793a2d